# What's the best way to hard a BehaviourSubject in RxJava2?

Tags: java, rx-java, rx-java2, behaviorsubject

I'm getting into RxJava and am looking for a good way to share a number of BehaviourSubjects with multiple subscribers. Each BehaviourSubject is identified by a unique subject and only one subscription should be made to the back end for each subject.

If there are no current subscribers for the BehaviourSubject it should unsubscribe from the back end.

The following code does what I want, but the MyFakeService class lacks the elegance I that RxJava promises.

```
package au.play;

import io.reactivex.Observable;
import io.reactivex.disposables.Disposable;
import io.reactivex.functions.Consumer;
import io.reactivex.observers.DisposableObserver;
import io.reactivex.subjects.BehaviorSubject;

import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReference;

public class Demo {
    public static class MyFakeBackEnd {
        private final Observable<Long> FAKE_SOURCE = Observable.interval(30, 10, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

        public Observable<Long> getObservable(String subject) {
            return FAKE_SOURCE;
        }
    }

    public static class MyFakeService {
        private final MyFakeBackEnd myFakeBackEnd = new MyFakeBackEnd();
        private final Map<String, Observable<Long>> subjectMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

        public Observable<Long> getObservable(String subject) {
            return subjectMap.computeIfAbsent(subject, (String key) -> {
                BehaviorSubject<Long> behaviourSubject = BehaviorSubject.createDefault(-1L);

                AtomicReference<Disposable> atomicDisposable = new AtomicReference<>();

                return behaviourSubject
                        .doOnSubscribe(disposable -> {
                            System.out.println("First subscriber for <" + key + ">");
                            final DisposableObserver<Long> disposableObserver = new DisposableObserver<Long>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onNext(Long value) {
                                    behaviourSubject.onNext(value);
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onComplete() {
                                    System.out.println("Why complete?");
                                }
                            };

                            myFakeBackEnd.getObservable(subject).subscribeWith(disposableObserver);
                            atomicDisposable.set(disposableObserver);
                        })
                        .doOnDispose(() -> {
                            System.out.println("Last observer unsubscribed : <" + key + ">");
                            atomicDisposable.get().dispose();
                            behaviourSubject.onNext(-2L);
                        }).share();
            });
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        MyFakeService service = new MyFakeService();

        System.out.println("C-1 subscription, should trigger 'First subscriber for <firstSubject>' and then start receiving updates. Initial value should be -1");
        Disposable firstDisposable = service.getObservable("firstSubject").subscribe(createConsumer("C-1"));

        Thread.sleep(45);

        System.out.println("C-2 subscription, should not trigger 'First subscriber for <firstSubject>'. Should receive same updates as C-1.");
        Disposable secondDisposable = service.getObservable("firstSubject").subscribe(createConsumer("C-2"));

        System.out.println("C-3 subscription, should trigger 'First subscriber for <secondSubject>' and then start receiving updates. Initial value should be -1");
        Disposable thirdDisposable = service.getObservable("secondSubject").subscribe(createConsumer("C-3"));

        Thread.sleep(45);

        System.out.println("Dispose of C-1 subscription. C-2 should continue getting updates.");
        firstDisposable.dispose();

        Thread.sleep(45);

        System.out.println("Dispose of C-2 subscription. Should trigger 'Last observer unsubscribed : <firstSubject>'.");
        secondDisposable.dispose();

        Thread.sleep(45);

        System.out.println("Dispose of C-3 subscription. Should trigger 'Last observer unsubscribed : <secondSubject>'.");
        thirdDisposable.dispose();

        Thread.sleep(45);

        System.out.println("C-4 subscription, should trigger 'First subscriber for <secondSubject>' and then start receiving updates. Initial value should be -2 as this subject has been subscribed to before.");
        Disposable fourthDisposable = service.getObservable("secondSubject").subscribe(createConsumer("C-3"));

        Thread.sleep(45);

        fourthDisposable.dispose();
    }

    private static Consumer<Long> createConsumer(final String id) {
        return (data) -> System.out.println(id + " : <" + data + ">");
    }
}
```

It seems very likely that there is a better solution to this that I can't spot because I'm new to the framework. Any ideas?

Comment: Other than a few potential concurrency problems (i.e., set the DisposableObserver reference in AtomicDisposable before subscribing to the backend on the first observer, calling `onNext` in `doOnDispose` may run on any thread and violate the serialization requirement of `onNext`), this is a reasonable way to achieve the desired effects. Perhaps refactor some code out into methods to reduce the indent depth.

Comment: Perhaps I don't understand the question. Does `.share()` not do what you want?

Comment: The code I've got works. It just feels a bit clumsy to be sticking the Disposable reference into an atomic and to having to construct a DipsosableObserver so that I've got something to dispose. I also thought that subscribing to a back end system and broadcasting the result to multiple subscribers would be a pretty standard use case so I didn't expect to have to .share() to isolate the first/last subscriptions. It sounds like I'm basically on the right track though, so I'll party on with connecting it to a real back end and see what happens. Thanks for you help.